# If statement not working for raw_input prompt

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.x, adventure

Everything left out of what is shown is correct because I tested it before...

no matter what i put, it still says "That is not a choice" which is my else statement

1 = choice1

2 = choice2

3 = choice3

```
while True:
    choice = raw_input("->")
    if choice == 1:
        dochoice1
        break
    elif choice == 2:
        dochoice2
        break
    elif choice == 3:
        dochoice3
        break
    else:
        print "That Is Not A Choice"
        continue
```

Comment: so no matter what i put, it still says "That is not a choice" which is my else statement...

Comment: @DuckyQuack `if` does not repeat, therefore it is not a loop-construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string, which you're comparing to integers, either convert `choice` to `int`, or compare it to string:

```
choice = int(raw_input("->"))
```

or:

```
if choice == "1":
```

If the user inputs something that's not a valid `int`, you can catch the exception:

```
try:
    choice = int(raw_input("->"))
except ValueError:
    print "Invalid int"
    continue
```

Comment: Why not just use `input` which returns an `int`?

Comment: @EliSadoff it is bad practice to use `input` in Python 2, since it calls `eval`.

Comment: but when i do that, if the reply or input is not an integer it has an error in the code

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo True. It allows for more UB as well.

Comment: and i tried the make it a string but it just wates 20 or something seconds and then says the code is finished

Comment: Of course it works. Your problem now is that you dont print anything when you have a valid choice. Or do you see a `print` statement anywhere in your code besides the `else` branch?